# Sort excel according to birthday

Tags: vba, excel

How to arrange a list according to birthday in an excel sheet?

```
SLno    Name    rollnumber   birthday
______________________________________
1       aaa        45         august 25th
2       ddfg       87         april 2nd
3       poiu       98         january 4th
```

In the above table i need the list to be updated according to birthday column?
expected o/p:

```
SLno    Name    rollnumber   birthday
______________________________________
1       poiu       98         january 4th 
2       ddfg       87         april 2nd
3       aaa        45         august 25th
```

Comment: Use real dates (not text) in the birthday column and Excel will sort it for you in one click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best option is to use `DateSerial` numbers for the birthday, formatted to display as you want.

If you can't convert, try this

Add a helper column with a formula to convert the birthday to a `DateSerial` and sort on that column

Formula (assuming birthday is in column `D`):

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(D2,FIND(" ",D2)+1,LEN(D2)-FIND(" ",D2)-2)&" "&LEFT(D2,FIND(" ",D2)-1)&" 1900")
```

Answer (score 2):

using the helper column idea that @chrisneilsen gave, a different formula for the helper column would be:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(D2,LEN(D2)-2)&", 2012")
```

This takes the last 2 letters off the date you have (as Excel does not understand ordinals), and converts it into a date by appending ", 2012" to that new text, and reading the date.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of data you could use a script like this to convert your date format to numbers. I'm assuming from your sample that the birthdays are in Column D, if not then just change below.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ChangeFormat()
    With Columns("D").Cells
        .Replace What:="January", Replacement:="01", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        .Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="/", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        .Replace What:="th", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        .Replace What:="nd", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        .Replace What:="st", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        .Replace What:="rd", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

You can then sort it by date.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, you will need to have one column with properly formatted dates to enable sorting.

But then you can have a second column with the visual format you like with this nifty formula I found on on [another site](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/677702-date-format-of-just-st-nd-rd-and-th.html) to reformat your dates how you want them. I changed the original to match your format.

```
=LOWER(TEXT(A1,"mmmm d"))&LOOKUP(DAY(A1),{1,2,3,4,21,22,23,24,31;"st","nd","rd","th","st","nd","rd","th","st"}) &TEXT(A1,", yyyy")
```